# Make directory look like variable in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am lost, I am trying to make my website work like this:

Domain.com/ABC should redirect to Domain.com/index.html?user=ABC

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)$ /index.html?user=$1 [L]
```

I tried this but it only returns 404 error :( I tried few solutions and none worked out :/

Comment: Do you have a file called `index.html` in the root folder, or is it called `index.php` (since you tagged the question with php)?

Comment: Yes, I have index.html, I am operating with parametrs using Javascript, my bad, no idea why I added php tag, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.html?user=$1 [L]
```

Because there is no `/` at the beginning of the left test for a .htaccess
And -f,-d because we must exclude other existing url